# Ordering Disabled in TFS Backlog

Tags: tfs, backlog

I am managing an agile project in TFS.  When I click on the current sprint on the left hand side of the TFS web app, the stories in the sprint are listed out as normal, but there is now a message stating that:

Ordering backlog items is disabled, because this iteration contains nested backlog items. Learn how to fix this.

When I click on the "Learn how to fix this." link, the MS page that comes up speaks about nested work items in the backlog, but doesn't really give any clue about how to detect the nested backlog items.  Each story in my list naturally has Tasks created for each story, but as far as I can detect this is the only level of nesting there is.  This should not be enough to disable ordering, however, because my other TFS project also has stories broken down into tasks and ordering is NOT disable for that project.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: have you read this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fbc58bde-f758-433c-8891-ade3981c2b00/ordering-backlog-items-is-disabled-because-this-iteration-contains-nested-backlog-items?forum=TFService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that one of the bugs in the sprint was a child of one of the stories in the sprint.  I changed the relationship from parent to related and then I was able to reorder the work items again.